# How to comment List item?

Tags: vimscript

There are times I want to comment List items:

```
let test_data = [
      \ " description in comment
      \ complicated_data0
      \
      \ " description in comment
      \ complicated_data1
      ...
      \ ]

----
result error:

E114: Missing quote: " description in comment 0 ]
```

`E114` is thrown as it's missing the enclosing`"`.

What's the common workaround ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since patch 8.1.0369 you can comment continuation lines.  However, you must follow the `"\` syntax:

```
let test_data = [
      "\ description in comment
      \ complicated_data0
      \
      "\ description in comment
      \ complicated_data1
      ...
      \ ]
```

Prior to that, you would need to split the list up into pieces:

```
" description in comment
let test_data = [
      \ 1,
      \ ]
" description in comment",
let test_data += [
      \ 2,
      \ ]
```

Comment: Thanks, both works. There is a typo in first line, it's `"\ `, not `\"`.